# CMFCPopupMenu - RightClick Context menu shortcut keys disappear for some reason

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm having a problem with the RMB Context menus, In my main frame I have a grid control with the RMB context menu event. The shortcut keys appear correctly. See Copy for Ctrl + C,Paste for Ctrl + V, etc...

[image: Correct]

Then I have a dialog with already a bunch of codes from other dev's. And this dialog somehow makes the RMB Context menu funky. The shortcut keys no longer appear. It may be caused by altering the PreTransalateMessage and some messages are not going through right or maybe some shell functions that may had a conflict. Because when you notice the window it's still using the windows aero basic theme while I'm using Windows 10 because of the pin icon beside the minimize.

[image: Incorrect]

This is the code used in the mainframe as well as in the dialog.

```
void MyDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint ptMousePos)
{
    CMenu *menuRightClick;
    menuRightClick->LoadMenu(IDR_RIGHTCLICK);
    CMenu *pPopupVitmMenu;
    pPopupVitmMenu = menuRightClick->GetSubMenu(9);
    ASSERT(pPopupVitmMenu);

    if (pPopupVitmMenu)
    {
        CPoint point;
        ::GetCursorPos(&point);

        CMFCPopupMenu* pPopupMenu = new CMFCPopupMenu;

        CMFCPopupMenu* pPopup = CMFCPopupMenu::GetActiveMenu();
        //close already poped up menus, if any.
        if (pPopup != NULL)
            pPopup->CloseMenu();

        pPopupMenu->Create(this, point.x, point.y, pPopupVitmMenu->Detach(), FALSE, TRUE);

        pPopupMenu->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
}
```

This maybe related or unrelated but the old context menu doesn't get dimissed when you RMB on another area. It only disappears when you click outside the application(Desktop,Taskbar).

[image]

I know the information is vague, but that's all I can provide.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better use `CContextMenuManager::ShowPopupMenu` to display context menus. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982387.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: No luck, I used CWinAppEx::GetContextMenuManager then used it's member function ShowPopupMenu problem still persists.

Comment: Did you already clean the registry cache on registry? The `Workspace` subfolder of your application.

Comment: Looking to `CKeyboardManager::UpdateAccelTable` last parameter, we get to know the accelerator table is only applied to `CFrameWnd*` derived objects. I had a case here of an app that has several  `CFrameWnd*` derived objects and I had to make the the accelerator table of my real main window shared with the others by calling manually `theApp.GetKeyboardManager()->UpdateAccelTable(NULL, pMainFrame->m_hAccelTable, (CFrameWnd*) pSecFrame)` in each `pSecFrame` initialization. (to be continued...)

Comment: (...continuation) I had also to prevent destruction of the now shared accelerator table when a secondary frame gets destructed, on its response to `ON_WM_DESTROY()`, defined by method `CSecondaryFrame::OnDestroy` , by using ` m_hAccelTable = NULL;__super::OnDestroy();` Then the __super class constructor will be faked and will not see the real table, and will not destroy it.

Comment: I don't know what class are your dialogs and whether they are modal or modeless. If the case is not same as mine, I think my answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `theApp.GetContextMenuManager()` to get access to `CContextMenuManager`. Where `theApp` is the main `CWinApp` class. It should be calling `InitContextMenuManager()` during initialization.

```
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MAINFRAME);
CMenu *popup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
if(popup)
{
    CContextMenuManager *manager = theApp.GetContextMenuManager();
    if(manager)
        //for CDialogEx:
        manager->ShowPopupMenu(popup->Detach(), p.x, p.y, this, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE);
        //for CDialog:
        //manager->ShowPopupMenu(popup->Detach(), p.x, p.y, this, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
}
```

Note that the 5th parameter should be `TRUE` for `CDialogEx`, and `FALSE` for `CDialog`

Comment: CContextMenuManager *manager = GetApp()->GetContextMenuManager();
  manager->ShowPopupMenu(pPopupVitmMenu->GetSafeHmenu(), point.x, point.y, this, 0, 1, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your MyDialog is either of type CDialogEx or CMFCPropertyPage.

Within the CMFCPopupMenu::Create function, the CMFCPopupMenu::NotifyParentDlg function will be invoked.

```
BOOL CMFCPopupMenu::NotifyParentDlg(BOOL bActivate)
{
    CDialogEx* pDlg = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDialogEx, m_pMessageWnd);
    CMFCPropertyPage* pPropPage = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCPropertyPage, m_pMessageWnd);

    if (pDlg == NULL && pPropPage == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!bActivate && m_pActivePopupMenu != this)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (pDlg != NULL)
    {
        pDlg->SetActiveMenu(bActivate ? this : NULL);
    }

    if (pPropPage != NULL)
    {
        pPropPage->SetActiveMenu(bActivate ? this : NULL);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The deletion of the popup menu is contingent upon whether the parent or message window has set the active menu.